# How Keras can calculate the number of parameters at early stage when there are still None dimensions?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, parameters, resnet

Sorry for the very basic question (I'm new with Keras). I was wondering how Keras can calculate for each layer the number of parameters at an early stage (before fit) despite that model.summary shows that there are dimensions that still have None values at this stage. Are these values already determined in some way and if yes, why not show them in the summary?

I ask the question because I'm having a hard time figure out my "tensor shape bug" (I'm trying to determine the output dimensions of the the C5 block of my resnet50 model but I cannot see them in model.summary even if I see the number of parameters).

I give below an example based on C5_reduced layer in RetinaNet which is fed by C5 layer of Resnet50. The C5_reduced is

```
Conv2D(256,kernel_size=1,strides=1,pad=1)
```

Based on model.summary for this particular layer:

```
C5_reduced (Conv2D)    (None, None, None, 256)          524544
```

I've made the guess that C5 is (None,1,1,2048) because 2048*256+256 = 524544 (I don't know how to confirm or infirm that hypothesis). So if it's already known, why not show it on summary? If dimensions 2 and 3 would have been different, the number of parameters would have been different too right?

Comment: Can you add your codes? It will be easy to give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass exact input shape to your very first layer or input layer on your network, you will have the output that you want. For instance I used input layer here:

```
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928
```

Passed input as (224,224,3). 3 represents the depth here. Note that convolutional parameters' calculation differ from Dense layers' calculation.

If you do such following:

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3))
```

You will see:

```
conv2d (Conv2D) ---> (None, 148, 148, 16)
```

Dimensions reduced to 148x148, in Keras padding is `valid` by default. Also `strides` is 1. Then the shape of output will be 148 x 148. (You can search for the formula.)

So then what are **None** values?

- First ***None*** value is the batch size. In Keras first dimension is the batch size. You can pass them and make fixed, or you can determine them while fitting the model, or predicting.
- In 2D convolution, the expected input is **(batch_size, height, width, channels)**, you can also have shapes such as **(None, None, None, 3)**, that means varying image sizes are allowed.

Edit:

```
tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (None, None, 3)),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu')
```

Produces:

```
conv2d_21 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 16)    448
```

Regarding to your question, how are the parameters calculated even we passed image height & width as **None**?

Convolution parameters calculated according to:

```
(filter_height * filter_width * input_image_channels + 1) * number_of_filters
```

When we put them into formula,

```
filter_height = 3
filter_width = 3
input_image_channel = 3
number_of_filters = 16
```

**Parameters = (3 x 3 x 3 + 1) * 16 = 28 * 16 =  448**

Notice, we only needed input_image's channel number which is 3, representing that it is an RGB image.

If you want to calculate the params for later convolutions, you need to consider that the number of filters from previous layer becomes the number of channels for current layer's channel.

That's how you can end up having **None** params rather than batch_size. Keras needs to know if your image is RGB or not in that case. Or you won't specify the dimensions while creating the model and can pass them while fitting the model with the dataset.

Comment: Thanks Frightera but my question remains: why not show the "width" and "height" values (at upper levels I understand that these are not width and height dimensions anymore) in summary? Am I correct when I say that these values are known since we can see the number of parameters

Comment: or stated otherwise how can we see number of parameters in summary when some dimensions (other than the batch dimension) are None? It's probably because these values are known, right? So if it's the case, why not show them?

Comment: and if it's not the case, how can the number of parameters be determined since it depends on the specific values of width and height dimensions?

Comment: I edited my answer, see if your question is answered. If not, feel free to ask further :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an input layer for your model.  The total number of trainable parameters is unknown until you either a) compile the model and feed it data, at which point the model makes a graph based on the dimensions of the input and you will then be able to determine the number of params, or b) you define an input layer for the model with the input dimensions stated, then you can find the number of params with model.summary().

The point is that the model cannot know the number of parameters between the input and first hidden layer until it is defined, or you run inference and give it the shape of the input.

Comment: Thanks devboydan. But my question remains: why not show the "real" numbers in model.summary if they are known (and they are known since the number of parameters is shown).